# Vuforia Video Playback is flickering in Unity app?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am developing an augmented reality application using Vuforia(8.1.10) in Unity.
Everything is working perfectly fine but the video is flickering very often. In fact, every time when the camera moves slightly the video is wavering like anything. It is shaking quite often. This is reducing the augmented reality experience.

I am attaching `quad` to `ImageTarget`. And in the quad, I am attaching the video player. The video is a chroma key video. To remove chroma, I am using the shader.

What should I do to make the video playback more stable? Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to change Your **ARCamera Clipping Planes** Near and Far options.

**Try 0.05 for Near and 2000 for Far**

I hope that helps and if it doesn't I'd suggest you to tinker around with the Clipping Plane values until it stops buffering. 
Updating the Vuforia Engine to 8.1 is also recommended in case of bug fixes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But clipping planes is already set to that value. And I have vuforia `8.1`. I have update my question. Any other possible solution to this?

Comment: In my case this value is already set but it's still flickering

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Vuforia Configuration like this,

**ARCamera --> Open Vuforia Engine Configuration --> Device Tracker --> Track Device Pose = checkmark (True) and Tracking Mode = Positional**